PowerBI DAX Measure: Sum of SalesAmount in future periods where data provides a single value and start date
I'm working on a revenue forecast using data from Salesforce that provides, for each Opportunity[Id], a close date and a single value for Monthly revenue (Annual revenue is also available if it makes the code easier to read/understand).
I appreciate your time and assistance with this problem.
Data in Model:



Opportunity[Id]
Opportunity[close date]
Opportunity[Monthly Weighted Revenue]




A
2024-09-20
10


B
2024-11-12
40


C
2024-10-24
20



Note: Opportunity[close date] is related to 'Calendar'[Date]
Requirement output #1:



Opportunity[Id]
Jul'24
Aug'24
Sep'24
Q2'24
Oct'24
Nov'24
Dec'24
Q4'24
FY'24




A
0.00
0.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
10.00
30.00
40.00


B
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
40.00
40.00
80.00
80.00


C
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
60.00
60.00


Total
0.00
0.00
10.00
10.00
30.00
70.00
70.00
170.00
180.00



Requirement output #2:
Note: values for Opportunity A contribute to the total in Q4'24 even though it has a close date in Q3'24 which isn't in the current filter context. Other filters such as Opportunity[status] still need to filter the report.



Opportunity[Id]
Q4'24
FY'24




Total
170.00
170.00



Current Code:
My current measure repeats the monthly weighted revenue when rendered in a table visual with columns for Opportunity[Id] and months, however, it doesn't work when I remove Opportunity[Id] and it doesn't work for subtotals. I've tried various iterations of SUMX() over a table that calls the variable "_Monthly_Weighted_Revenue_Fixed_Repeating", but none have worked so far.
MRW extended = 
VAR _CurrentMonth =
    MAX('Calendar'[Date])
VAR _CloseMonth = 
    CALCULATE(
        EOMONTH( MAX(Opportunity[CloseDate] ), 0 ),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar')
    )
VAR _Monthly_Weighted_Revenue_Fixed = // stores the value corresponding with the single close date in a way it can be called from any period.
    CALCULATE(
        [Monthly Revenue Weighted],
        REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar')
    )
VAR _Monthly_Weighted_Revenue_Fixed_Repeating = // this repeats the above value for all future months.
    IF(
        _CurrentMonth >= _CloseMonth,
        _Monthly_Weighted_Revenue_Fixed,
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN _Monthly_Weighted_Revenue_Fixed_Repeating

Update Fri, Aug 21 '24:
I have the below code working tentatively.

Open to refactoring suggestions.
satisfies my two required outputs above, but haven't tested for unexpected results with report filters or slicers.

Monthly Revenue Weighted =
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN( // returns a table with all combinations of opportunity[Id] and Date (as EOM)
            CALCULATETABLE( TREATAS ( DISTINCT( Opportunity[Id]), Opportunity[Id] ), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
            TREATAS(DISTINCT('Calendar'[Date as EOM]),'Calendar'[Date])
        ),
        "closeDate", CALCULATE( EOMONTH(MAX(Opportunity[CloseDate]),0), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
        "MRW" ,
        IF( // returns monthly weighted revenue beginning on the close date and continuing into future periods.
            'Calendar'[Date] >= CALCULATE( EOMONTH(MAX(Opportunity[CloseDate]),0), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
            CALCULATE(
                [Annual Revenue Weighted] / 12,
                REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar')
            ),
            BLANK()
        )
    ),
    [MRW]
)


For Id = A the close date 2024-09-20 while in your calculation Sept 24= 10 and it continues until the end of the year.
Can you explain the logic ?

Yes. For my purposes, I don't care about the day of the close date, only the year and month. If we sign on a customer that is assumed to generate $10 in monthly revenue, I want the total pipeline to reflect that amount in all future months including the month in which the opportunity is expected to close. 'Sep'24' is formatting for "September, 2024", not September 24th.

Update Fri, Aug 21 '24:
I have the below code working tentatively.
Monthly Revenue Weighted =
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CROSSJOIN( // returns a table with all combinations of opportunity[Id] and Date (as EOM)
            CALCULATETABLE( TREATAS ( DISTINCT( Opportunity[Id]), Opportunity[Id] ), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
            TREATAS(DISTINCT('Calendar'[Date as EOM]),'Calendar'[Date])
        ),
        "closeDate", CALCULATE( EOMONTH(MAX(Opportunity[CloseDate]),0), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
        "MRW" ,
        IF( // returns monthly weighted revenue beginning on the close date and continuing into future periods.
            'Calendar'[Date] >= CALCULATE( EOMONTH(MAX(Opportunity[CloseDate]),0), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar') ),
            CALCULATE(
                [Annual Revenue Weighted] / 12,
                REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar')
            ),
            BLANK()
        )
    ),
    [MRW]
)

